# How to automate extraction of values represented by numpy array associated with keys as separate data from a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that contains values that are saved within multiple numpy arrays for each key.  I want to extract the values from each key in an automated way rather than individually go through each key to extract the values with for instance dictname[key1], dictname[key2], etc.

I have tried 'for' loops, but that is not working and being a beginner I can't work out where I am going wrong. See below:

```
type(Win_mapping) = class 'collections.defaultdict'
```

keys list :

```
Win_mapping.keys()

Out:
dict_keys([(3, 8), (2, 5), (2, 8), (1, 8), (2, 7), (3, 7), (3, 6), (2,   6), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1, 4), (0, 7), (6, 5), (3, 5), (4, 4), (4, 6)])
```

Example of some of the values for the first key

```
Win_mapping[(3, 8)]

Out:
[array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.33000017e-27,   1.73497305e-03,
     -8.36198378e-05,   2.74863690e-01], dtype=float32),
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.33999998e-27,   1.19663752e-03,
     -2.99715757e-05,   2.62920409e-01], dtype=float32),
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.35000018e-27,   6.05389301e-04,
     -3.59380065e-05,   2.54130781e-01], dtype=float32),
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.36000000e-27,   3.28844151e-04,
     -8.31774960e-05,   2.48996541e-01], dtype=float32),
 array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.36999981e-27,   3.52510775e-04,
     -1.14181137e-04,   2.47686639e-01], dtype=float32)]
```

For loop example:

```
for key, value in Win_mapping:
    node_key = [value]
    print(node_key)

[8]
[5]
[8]
[8]
[7]
[7]
[6]
[6]
[7]
[6]
[4]
[7]
[5]
[5]
[4]
[6]
```

This is just a representation of the second number for each key e.g. (3, 8), (2, 5), etc.

The result I want is an automated method to extract the values within each key then at the same time, and I am not sure this is possible, using just the position of the key in the list rather than the keys name.  This is because I am setting up code which will hopefully take in different dictionaries with different key names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dict.items`  to access the key-value

**Ex:**

```
for key, value in Win_mapping.items():
    node_key = [value]
    print(node_key)
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, that did run but before it finished running I got the error: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs).  Clearly I need to think about how I optimise the amount of memory the computation is taking up